# How to change shape of specific point in a plot in R

Tags: r, plot

How can I change the shape of specific points in an R plot? I have a plot with four points, and I would like to change the shape of two points `(0, 0.4991)` and `(1, 1.2258)`in the following plot:

```
x = c(0,0,1,1,1)
y = c(0.4991,1.1423,1.2258,1.158,0.5148)
dat<-cbind(x,y)

myTicks<-c(0,1)
plot(dat[,1],dat[,2], yaxt="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")
abline(0.4991,0.7267)
abline(1.1423,0.0157)
abline(0.4991,0.0157,lty=2)
axis(side = 1, at = myTicks)
axis(side = 2, at = myTicks)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the shape with `pch` parameter, which accept vectors, for example

```
x = c(0,0,1,1,1)
y = c(0.4991,1.1423,1.2258,1.158,0.5148)
point_shape = c(10,15,10,15,15)
dat<-data.frame(x,y,point_shape)

myTicks<-c(0,1)
plot(dat[,1],dat[,2], yaxt="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", pch = dat$point_shape)
abline(0.4991,0.7267)
abline(1.1423,0.0157)
abline(0.4991,0.0157,lty=2)
axis(side = 1, at = myTicks)
axis(side = 2, at = myTicks)
```

[image]